# Importing SQL query into Pandas results in only 1 column

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

I'm trying to import the results of a complex SQL query into a pandas dataframe. My query requires me to create several temporary tables since the final result table I want includes some aggregates. 
My code looks like this:

```
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER=foo;SERVER=bar;etc')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SQL QUERY HERE')
    cursor.execute('SECONDARY SQL QUERY HERE')
    ...
    df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(),columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])
```

I get an error that tells me shapes aren't matching:

```
    ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1,900000),indices imply (5,900000)
```

And indeed, the result of all the SQL queries should be a table with 5 columns rather than 1. I've run the SQL query using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and it works and returns the 5 column table that I want. I've tried to not pass any column names into the dataframe and printed out the head of the dataframe and found that pandas has put all the information in 5 columns into 1. The values in each row is a list of 5 values separated by commas, but pandas treats the entire list as 1 column. Why is pandas doing this? I've also tried going the `pd.read_sql` route but I still get the same error.

EDIT:

I have done some more debugging, taking the comments into account. The issue doesn't appear to stem from the fact that my query is nested. I tried a simple (one line) query to return a 3 column table and I still got the same error. Printing out `fetchall()` looks like this:

```
    [(str1,str2,str3,datetime.date(stuff),datetime.date(stuff)), 
    (str1,str2,str3,datetime.date(stuff),datetime.date(stuff)),...]
```

Comment: Have you tried running the queries together in an anonymous code block, e.g., `'SET NOCOUNT ON; SQL_QUERY_1; SQL_QUERY_2;'`?

Comment: Just tried that and got the same exact error.

Comment: can you Union the two results?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of how cursor.fetchall() looks like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.from_records` instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(),
                               columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])
```

Comment: Great, that did the trick! By the way, the command is cursor.description, I typo'd it when I typed the question. I will edit my question for that.

Answer (score 2):

Simply adjust the `pd.DataFrame()` call as right now `cursor.fetchall()` returns one-length list of tuples. Use `tuple()` or `list` to map child elements into their own columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([tuple(row) for row in cur.fetchall()],
                  columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])
```